# I'm making a Roblox exploit using WeAreDevs and I have this error. What is the problem with my text? (CS1061)

Tags: roblox

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    WeAreDevs_API.ExploitAPI aPI = new WeAreDevs_API.ExploitAPI();

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        aPI.LaunchExploit();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        fastColoredTextBox1.Clear();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        aPI.SendFullLuaScript(fastColoredTextBox1.Text);
    }
}
```

This is my problem something close to the ExploitApi Area.

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft's docs around the compiler error, [CS1061](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1061), this is caused by trying to call a function or access a property on an object that does not have that field.

Looking at the [documentation for the WeAreDevs API](https://wearedevs.net/d/Exploit%20API), it looks like *SendFullLuaScript()* isn't a real function. It looks like you want *SendScript()* instead.

Be aware that exploits are explicitly disallowed in Roblox's Terms of Service and you will likely be banned if you are caught using them.

Answer (score 0):

- In WeAreDevs API (V1), there isn't any function named `SendFullLuaScript()`. You must replace the `SendFullLuaScript()` fuction to `SendLimitedLuaScript()` function.
- Using these exploit are violating `Roblox's Terms of Service`. And WeAreDevs API is not a good exploit to exploiting secure. Yeah, if you continue exploiting, it is very high quality to will be get banned from Roblox.
- Goodluck ^^

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
aPI.SendFullLuaScript(fastColoredTextBox1.Text);
```

with

```
aPI.SendLuaScript(fastColoredTextBox1.Text);
```

Viewing the documenation: https://wearedevs.net/d/Exploit%20API, SendFullLuaScript is not a method of the latest version of the API. The previous method name was SendLimitedLuaScript, but that is now deprecated in favor of SendLuaScript.